# How to authenticate and access sharepoint online rest API in Phonegap with Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, sharepoint, ionic-framework

I referred this link

[Visit: http://www.elylucas.net/post/authenticating-with-sharepoint-online-in-a-ionicangularphonegap-app/](http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/)
[Authenticate Sharepoint API](http://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/)

From the above link I am using this function and got security token Successfully but i can't able to get `Set-Cookie` header response i have to send this cookie to every sharepoint api request to get api response successful but I am struggling on this.
Please help me.

```
function getBearerToken(result, url) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var securityToken = $($.parseXML(result)).find("BinarySecurityToken").text();

    if (securityToken.length == 0) {
        deferred.reject();
    }
    else {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: securityToken,
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        }).success(function (data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function () {
            deferred.reject();
        });
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

});

Comment: Hello, I'm having same issue with you, did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes. I resolved. have you done?

Comment: I'm not able to get cookies from the response headers! Can you add how do you get the cookies? thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your own solution to help others with the same issue, if possible,